# random_case(random_name) - Why won't the method to retrieve random data work?

Tags: ruby, random, methods

I have written the following code to retrieve "Random Case" and "Random name". All forum advice is to use the code as set out in the last "random_both" method. The aim is to return Random names "Ollie" and "Ana" either random(upcase / downcase). The code prints the right answer to the console but doesn't pass all the required tests? Why?

'''

```
name = "Jordan"

def upper(string)
  string.upcase
end

def lower(string)
  string.downcase
end

def random_name
  ["Ollie", "Ana"].sample
end

def random_case(string)
  [upper(string), lower(string)].sample
end

def random_both(string)

random_case(random_name) 

end
'''
```

Other methods I attempted that returned JORDAN instead of "Ollie , Ana" are :

'''

```
def random_both(string)
puts mixm = [random_name + random_case] 
end
```

### '''

'''

```
def random_both(string)
 mixm = Proc.new{  
  y =  [upper(string), lower(string)].sample
  j = ["Ollie", "Ana"].sample
  k = [y, j].sample
 }
```

end

mixm.call

'''

What other simpler solutions could work?

Thank you!

Comment: What are the  failing test cases? Might it have to do with the fact that your `random_both` method accepts a string argument that is unused?

Comment: Thank you for your comments . The failed tests : wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
/home/runner/main.rb:19:in `random_both'
/home/runner/__spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/

Comment: Pressed enter! Thank you for your reply the failed test is 
" :has_a_working_random_both_method ". I removed the (string) on random_both but that failed tests completely : error msg - wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
(repl):19:in `random_both'
(repl):38:in `<main>'

Comment: What is the failure when you add back the argument?

Comment: AHH! I checked the given 1, expected 0 against the puts code, after the method : puts "My name is #{random_both()}" : and removed name from #{random_both(name)}. I hadn't put that line of code in the main text block - apologies. Any comments on if the error msg refers to "My name is #{random_both()}" and why removing the "name"   is the right answer? Thank you for your comments

Comment: Well, if you've defined `random_both` to take 1 argument, and you're supplying 0 arguments in the tests ... that's a problem. Just remember in the future to always include your full code on StackOverflow questions. In this case, the actual problem was in code you didn't show. Since this problem is now solved, are you able to make your own answer?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The code should have been added to the main code. First time using stackoverflow and I have resolved the answer. All comments are still helpful for code syntax and comprehension of the significance of removing 'name'. Thank you

Comment: So the question doesn't appear unsolved. you can write an answer for it yourself. You can accept it in 2 days.